# SetMovementMethods - ScrollingMovementMethod with LinkMovementMethod

Tags: android, scroll, textview, spannable, linkmovementmethod

I am new to Android Studio/Java.I have composed a script which creates a `TextView` contains a number of lines of information.  I want to make each line clickable, to create a Toast dialog for example, which content relevant to that entry.  This I can do.

I also want the `TextView` to be scrollable.  I can do this too...... but NOT both.

I am guessing from what I have read that one command cancels the other.  Here is the code I am trying to use.  Is there another way to enable this?

`responseTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
responseTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
responseTextView.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by changing the activity_main.xml to place the TextView inside a ScrollView control.

```
<ScrollView android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSearch" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblOutput"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="Awaiting Results..."
    android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSearch" />

</ScrollView>
```